# Analysis proof concerning series of differentiable functions with some pretty involved quantifiers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, derivatives, proof-verification

I'm working on this proof for analysis, but it's got quite a lot of quantifiers being used in different spots in different ways and it's not the first time they've messed me up in a proof, so I was just looking to see if what I have is good or if anything needs fixing, and I have a question about it, which I'll save for after the proof.

$\mathbf{Lemma.}$ *Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of differentiable functions on $(a,b)$. Suppose $\{f_n\}$ converges to a function $f$ and $\{f_n'\}$ converges to a function $g$. Then $f$ is also differentiable with derivative $g$ on $(a,b)$.*

$Proof.$ First observe that by the Main Limit Theorem, for any distinct $x,y\in(a,b)$, since $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ and $f_n(y)\to f(y)$, it also holds that $\frac{f_n(x)}{x-y}\to\frac{f(x)}{x-y}$ and $\frac{f_n(y)}{x-y}\to\frac{f(y)}{x-y}$. Thus, for all distinct $x,y\in(a,b)$ and for all $\epsilon\gt0$, there is an $N_1$ such that $$\left\lvert\frac{f(x)-f_n(x)}{x-y}\right\rvert\lt\frac\epsilon 4\,\text{whenever}\,n\gt N_1$$ and there is an $N_2$ such that $$\left\lvert\frac{f(y)-f_n(y)}{x-y}\right\rvert\lt\frac\epsilon 4\,\text{whenever}\,n\gt N_2.$$

Now, since $f_n'\to g$, we also have that for any $\epsilon\gt0$ and for any $y\in(a,b)$, there is an $N_3$ such that $$\left\lvert f_n'(y)-g(y)\right\rvert\lt\frac\epsilon 4\,\text{whenever}\,n\gt N_3.$$

Then, since $f_n$ is differentiable at $y$ for all $n$ and for all $y\in(a,b)$, for each $\epsilon\gt0$ there is a $\delta\gt0$ such that $$\left\lvert\frac{f_n(x)-f_n(y)}{x-y}-f_n'(y)\right\rvert\lt\frac\epsilon 4\,\text{whenever}\,x\in(a,b)\,\text{and}\,0\lt\lvert x-y\rvert\lt\delta$$

Finally, if we fix $\epsilon\gt0$ and $y\in(a,b)$ and set $N=\max\{N_1,N_2,N_3\}$, then whenever $n\gt N$, $x,y\in(a,b)$ and $0\lt\lvert x-y\rvert\lt\delta$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left\lvert\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-g(y)\right\rvert&=\left\lvert\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-\frac{f_n(x)-f_n(y)}{x-y}+\frac{f_n(x)-f_n(y)}{x-y}-f_n'(y)+f_n'(y)-g(y)\right\rvert\\
&=\left\lvert\frac{f(x)-f_n(x)}{x-y}-\frac{f(y)-f_n(y)}{x-y}+\frac{f_n(x)-f_n(y)}{x-y}-f_n'(y)+f_n'(y)-g(y)\right\rvert\\
&\le\left\lvert\frac{f(x)-f_n(x)}{x-y}\right\rvert+\left\lvert\frac{f(y)-f_n(y)}{x-y}\right\rvert+\left\lvert\frac{f_n(x)-f_n(y)}{x-y}-f_n'(y)\right\rvert+\left\lvert f_n'(y)-g(y)\right\rvert\\
&\lt\frac\epsilon 4+\frac\epsilon 4+\frac\epsilon 4+\frac\epsilon 4\\
&=\epsilon.
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, $f$ is differentiable with derivative $g$ on $(a,b)$.

$\mathbf{Proposition.}$ *Let $\{f_k\}$ be a sequence of differentiable functions on $(a,b)$ and suppose there is a point $c\in(a,b)$ such that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(c)$ converges. Suppose also that the sequence of derivatives $\{f_k'\}$ satisfies $\lvert f_k'(x)\rvert\le M_k$ on $(a,b)$ and the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty M_k$ converges. Then the series defining
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)\,\text{and}\,g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k'(x)$$
converge on $(a,b)$ and $f$ is differentiable with derivative $g$ on $(a,b)$.*

$Proof.$ First note that the Comparison Test gives that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k'(x)$ converges on $(a,b)$.

Now, since $f_k$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ for all $k$, it is also continuous on $[c,x]$ (respectively $[x,c]$) for all $x\in(a,b)$ with $x\gt c$ (respectively $x\lt c$). Then, by the Mean Value Theorem, for each $k$ and for each $x\in(a,b)$ with $x\neq c$, there is a $c_k\in[\min\{c,x\},\max\{c,x\}]$ such that $$\left\lvert\frac{f_k(x)-f_k(c)}{x-c}\right\rvert=\lvert f_k'(c_k)\rvert\le M_k.$$ By the Comparison Test, the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{f_k(x)-f_k(c)}{x-c}$ converges.

Now, since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(c)$ converges, the Main Limit Theorem tells us that for any $x\in(a,b)$ with $x\neq c$, the following also converge:
$$
\begin{align}
\bullet&\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{f_k(c)}{x-c}\\
\bullet&\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{f_k(x)}{x-c}\\
\bullet&\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x),
\end{align}
$$
and thus $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)$ converges on $(a,b)$.

Then, by the previous lemma, $f$ is differentiable with derivative $g$ on $(a,b)$. This completes the proof.

Now, my question is, do I need uniform convergence here? The way I have it currently doesn't use it, but I feel like it should.

Comment: Doesn't your second claim satisfy the hypotheses of the Weierstrass M-test? That implies uniform convergence.

Comment: Wouldn't it tell us that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{f_k(x)-f_k(c)}{x-c}$ converges uniformly on $(a,c)\cup(c,b)$? I don't see how I'd deduce that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)$ converges uniformly on $(a,b)$, unless there's a theorem corresponding to the Main Limit Theorem for uniform convergence. Also, if my lemma is correct (I'm not entirely sure it is), then I don't need uniform convergence.

Comment: What is this 'main limit theorem?' I'm claiming that in the case you have this summability condition actually implies the uniform convergence you want.

Comment: "Suppose $a_n\to a$, $b_n\to b$, $c$ is a real number, and $k$ is a
natural number. Then
(a) $ca_n\to ca$;
(b) $a_n+b_n\to a+b$;
(c) $a_nb_n\to ab$;
(d) $a_n/b_n\to a/b$ if $b\neq0$ and $b_n\neq0$ for all $n$;
(e) $a_n^k\to a^k$;
(f) $a_n^{1/k}\to a^{1/k}$ if $a_n\ge0$ for all $n$."

Comment: So it's just the basic properties. Okay. Fine. It's true that sums of uniformly convergent sequences are uniformly convergent. For products I think boundedness of the functions are also needed.

Comment: Okay that's good to know. Is my lemma wrong though? If so, could you point out what needs fixed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66617/discussion-between-alfred-yerger-and-themathandlanguagetutor).

Comment: I can't access chat; the browser site never accepts my login information.

Comment: Sounds like a good thread for meta maybe... how to fix that problem. I believe what you have is OK - I can't find any errors but analysis isn't my forte. The point of my original comment is that the reason you appear not to use uniform convergence is because a) the Weierstrass M test implies uniform convergence of the derivative and b) Uniform convergence of the derivative + convergence at one point implies uniform convergence of the original sequence of functions. This is still true for series, as a series can be thought of as a sequence of partial sums.

Comment: @AlfredYerger This is old now but I was asking around and the problem is that my $\delta$ depends on $n$